# Finding the volume of an object with 3 parameters

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I want to find the volume of a rugby ball. But the question is more general.

I know how to find the volume of a sphere/ball around x-axis using:

$$
V = \pi \int_{a}^{b}f^2(x)dx
$$

Lets say if:

$$
x^2 + y^2 = r^2
$$

We do:

$$
y = \sqrt{r^2-x^2}
$$

So now:

$$
V = \pi \int_{-r}^{r}(\sqrt{r^2-x^2})^2dx
$$

But the problem starts here:

Im given an equation of ellipsoid, it has 3 parameters:

$$
x^2+4y^2+4z^2 \leq 4
$$

What do i do with the $z$ parameter? How do i build $y$ now? how does it fit to the equation by integrals of $V$?

I would like an explanation and not just a solution - because its homework.

Thanks!

Comment: You figure out the bounds for one variable, say $z$. For fixed $z$, figure out the bound of another variable, say $y$ and keep on repeat this process until all variables are covered...
$$\int_{x^2+4y^2+4z^2\le 4} dxdydz =
\int_{-1}^1\left(\int_{x^2+4y^2\le 4 - 4z^2} dx dy\right)dz\\
= \int_{-1}^1\left(\int_{-\sqrt{1-z^2}}^{\sqrt{1-z^2}} \left(\int_{x^2 \le 4 - 4z^2-4y^2} dx \right) dy \right)dz\\
= \int_{-1}^1\left(\int_{-\sqrt{1-z^2}}^{\sqrt{1-z^2}} \left(\int_{-\sqrt{4 - 4z^2-4y^2}}^{\sqrt{4 - 4z^2-4y^2}} dx \right) dy \right)dz
$$

Comment: A (perfectly spherical) ball with radius $r$ is the set of points $(x,y,z)$ such that $x^2+y^2+z^2\le r^2$. What happens to $z$ when you set up the integral to find the volume of the ball?

Answer (score 1):

In finding the volume of a ball $x^2+y^2+z^2\le r^2$, you revolve the curve $y=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ about the $y$-axis. Notice that $y=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ is the equation you get by setting $z=0$ in the equation for the sphere.

You can do the same thing with the ellipsoid: set $z=0$ to get the equation for the boundary of the rugby ball in the $(x,y)$-plane, and solve for $y$.

$$x^2+4y^2=4\implies y=\frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}2$$

Revolving this curve about the $y$-axis gives the volume,

$$\pi\int_{-2}^2\left(\frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}2\right)^2\,\mathrm dx=\frac\pi4\int_{-2}^24-x^2\,\mathrm dx=\frac{8\pi}3$$

Comment: We can just set $z = 0$? no problem with that?

Comment: Setting $z=0$ restricts you to a cross section of the ball along one of its axes of symmetry, so that revolving the boundary curve about the axis gives you a uniform shape. If instead you had, for instance, a sphere centered elsewhere like with $x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=r^2$, then you can focus on the cross section at $z=1$, which removes $z$ from the equation.

Comment: What about the $\leq  4$ how could you replase it by $=$? And thanks for the help, i start to understand. Now i try to understand why there is the $\leq$ there and not $=$?

Comment: I think its because z = 0 its the symmetric point with the maximum radius, an i right?

Comment: $x^2+y^2=r^2$ is a circle of radius $r$. $x^2+y^2\le r^2$ is a **disk** of radius $r$. The circle is the boundary of the disk. One is a curve, the other is a region.